# OCaml doing multiple things on one line

Tags: ocaml

I'm not exactly sure how to do this but lets say you have an if and else statement, and in the else clause I want to execute one statement, followed by another separate one.

For example:

```
let rec uniq_aux old_l new_l = match old_l with
    [] -> []
  | (h::t) ->
    if (contain h new_l) then
      uniq_aux t new_l
    else
      h::new_l ; (uniq_aux t new_l)
;;
```

in the last line in the code I want to add h to a new list (new_l) and keep recursing through the old list to process more info.

But I am getting an error on that line and at the line where I do: contain h new_l then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you want the expression `h :: new_l` to modify `new_l` so it contains a new element. However, OCaml doesn't work like that. OCaml variables are immutable. (Sorry to keep repeating this, but I hope it helps to break the habit of thinking imperatively.)

Assuming I'm right about what you want the code to do, the functional programming equivalent looks roughly like this:

```
let new_new_l = h :: new_l in
uniq_aux t new_new_l
```

In other words, you can define a *new* variable with the value you want, and use the new variable in place of the old one.

Comment: well you seem like you know ocaml very well. ya sorry imperative makes much more sense than this functional programming but I'll try my best to think non-imperatively.

Comment: wouldn't this also work: if (contain h new_l) then
      uniq_aux t new_l
    else
      uniq_aux t (h::new_l)

Comment: this way in the else clause I am recursively calling the function uniq_aux with the current h added to new_l

Comment: Yes! One of the great things about immutable values is that you can always substitute like this. So using `let` is often just for clarity.